# Where and how do you store your access_token and refresh_token in Oauth2.0 authorization flow

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

How should access and refresh tokens obtained from the Twitter API v2 be stored and used in a secure manner?

I can't just store access_token and refresh_token alone, right? I will need some kind of identifier. And probably save that identifier in the client.

Are there any recommended approaches or best practices for this? I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info from the [OWASP JWT for Java Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#token-storage-on-client-side) (the example code they have is in Javascript).

> 1. Store the token using the browser sessionStorage container, or use JavaScript closures with private variables
> 2. Add it as a Bearer HTTP Authentication header with JavaScript when calling services.
> 3. Add fingerprint information to the token.

or

> (4). An alternative to storing token in browser sessionStorage is to use JavaScript private variable or Closures. In this, access to all web requests are routed through a JavaScript module that encapsulates the token in a private variable which can not be accessed other than from within the module.
> And here are the implementation examples.

```js
/* Handle request for JWT token and local storage*/
function authenticate() {
    const login = $("#login").val();
    const postData = "login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&password=test";

    $.post("/services/authenticate", postData, function (data) {
        if (data.status == "Authentication successful!") {
            ...
            sessionStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
        }
        else {
            ...
            sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        ...
        sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    });
}



/* Handle request for JWT token validation */
function validateToken() {
    var token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token == undefined || token == "") {
        $("#infoZone").removeClass();
        $("#infoZone").addClass("alert alert-warning");
        $("#infoZone").text("Obtain a JWT token first :)");
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/services/validate",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            ...
        },
    });
}



function myFetchModule() {
    // Protect the original 'fetch' from getting overwritten via XSS
    const fetch = window.fetch;

    const authOrigins = ["https://yourorigin", "http://localhost"];
    let token = '';

    this.setToken = (value) => {
        token = value
    }

    this.fetch = (resource, options) => {
        let req = new Request(resource, options);
        destOrigin = new URL(req.url).origin;
        if (token && authOrigins.includes(destOrigin)) {
            req.headers.set('Authorization', token);
        }
        return fetch(req)
    }
}

...

// usage:
const myFetch = new myFetchModule()

function login() {
  fetch("/api/login")
      .then((res) => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
              return res.json()
          } else {
              throw Error(res.statusText)
          }
      })
      .then(data => {
          myFetch.setToken(data.token)
          console.log("Token received and stored.")
      })
      .catch(console.error)
}

...

// after login, subsequent api calls:
function makeRequest() {
    myFetch.fetch("/api/hello", {headers: {"MyHeader": "foobar"}})
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status == 200) {
                return res.text()
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText)
            }
        }).then(responseText => console.log("helloResponse", responseText))
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

Hope this helps!